# Cannot get Orchard CMS site to load on Network Solutions Windows Hosting

Tags: asp.net, windows, hosting, orchardcms, web-hosting

I get the following .NET error when trying to load my Orchard CMS website:

```
Access to the path '\\.........\www\App_Data\Dependencies\Lucene.dll' is denied.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\WDP\DFS\30\7\4\5\3024678547\user\sites\5481517.site\www\App_Data\Dependencies\Lucene.dll' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
```

How do I actually go about granting access rights? I've googled and found I should go into the server and right-click on the directory and edit the properties. BUT, I am in a shared hosting plan and don't think I can do that.

Am I pretty much at a dead end?

Things I've tried:

Setting file permissions through FTP, but I get a:

```
500 'SITE CHMOD 777...command not understood
```

I've downloaded and installed IIS Manager and successfully connected to my site, but still did not find any options to set permissions in there.

I've also called Network Solutions, but all I was told was to try to do the file permissions settings (as I mentioned above).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently the support staff at Network Solutions is very confused: they gave you a Unix command to execute on a Windows host. You should call them back and remind them you're on Windows.